# how to apply the style properties dynamically like bold, italic and font size when i select the particular icon?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, richtextbox

I want to turn the text area into a rich text editor inside Angular. So that when I click on the icon I want to apply the property to the selected text inside the textarea.

How can I achieve this by using angular6 and typescript? please help me. Thanks in advance.

[image].

Comment: What have you tried are you using any library? If not check this:https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

Comment: I achieve this by using a quill editor ( ngx-quill ) library.